# Не работает pyknow

Tags: python, pyknow

Импортировал библиотеки для ИИ:

```py
import pyknow.pyknow
from pyknow import *
```

При запуске программы выдаёт ошибки:

```py
from pyknow import abstract
ImportError: cannot import name 'abstract' from 'pyknow' (unknown location
```

Версия питона 3.8. Что делать?
Полный стек:

```
C:\Users\Tagir\PycharmProjects\ClassificationLab2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Tagir\PycharmProjects\ExpertSystemLab1\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tagir\PycharmProjects\ExpertSystemLab1\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyknow.pyknow
  File "C:\Users\Tagir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\pyknow\pyknow\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .engine import KnowledgeEngine
  File "C:\Users\Tagir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\pyknow\pyknow\engine.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyknow import abstract
ImportError: cannot import name 'abstract' from 'pyknow' (unknown location)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Если убрать import pyknow.pyknow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tagir\PycharmProjects\ExpertSystemLab1\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    class CanFly(Fact):
NameError: name 'Fact' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `import pyknow.pyknow` на `import pyknow`

Comment: `from pyknow import abstract` - но ведь у вас нет такого импорта? Или есть? Покажите **полный стек-трейс ошибки прямо в вопросе**, все строки, а не одну выборочную. Вполне может быть, что этот импорт делается в самой этой библиотеке, но мы не можем этого видеть без полного стек-трейса.

Comment: Я так изначально и делал, но тогда возникают ошибки такого рода: AttributeError: module 'pyknow' has no attribute 'Fact'. Так хотя бы факты, правила и классификатор можно определять

Comment: А зачем вам вообще `import pyknow.pyknow` или `import pyknow`? Во всех примерах к этой библиотеке на гитхабе я увидел только другой импорт из вашего кода: `from pyknow import *` и этого должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Без этого не работает ничего

Comment: С какими симптомами не работает? А примеры, которые на гитхабе приводятся - работают?

Comment: Ну пишет, к примеру, имя "Fact" не найдено

Comment: С гитхаба, скорее всего, тоже ничего работать не будет

Comment: Попробуйте вот этот форк: https://pypi.org/project/experta/ Я только его смог в Google Colab поставить через `pip` и пример прямо с титульной страницы там вполне работает. Насколько я понимаю, он в точности такой же как `pyknow`, кроме импорта ничего менять не нужно, всё должно работать так же.

Comment: Но вообще всё-таки покажите в вопросе и полный трейс ошибки, когда вы делаете только `from pyknow import *`, может что-то станет понятнее.

Comment: Добавил полный трейс